# Difference between these two async implementations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am using EF's async methods to fetch data from a database. Most of the time all is well. I have come into a few ObjectContextDisposed exceptions of late, and I am curious as to why my solution works:

Here was my original code that threw `ObjectContextDisposed`:

```
public Task<List<string>> GetEventParameterMru(EventParameter parameter, int count = 20)
{
    using (var repo = new ConfigurationRepository())
    {
        return repo.GetEventParameterMRU(_CurrentWorkpack, parameter, count)             
    }
}
```

Here is my new code that doesn't throw:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetEventParameterMru(EventParameter parameter, int count = 20)
{
    using (var repo = new ConfigurationRepository())
    {
        var result = await repo.GetEventParameterMRU(_CurrentWorkpack, parameter, count);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me what the difference is, and why it works?

Just FYI, in all my usages of this method, I call `await GetEventParameterMru()`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetEventParameterMRU` is apparently a method that starts a `Task` to retrieve some data. So `GetEventParameterMRU` returns before all operations on the `repo` have been completed.

Both version of your code use a `using` statement, which is translated into a `try/finally` block. In the `finally` block, `repo` will be *disposed*.

In your first version, you return *immediatly* after calling `GetEventParameterMRU` (starting the task). That means that `repo` is disposed immediatly while the `Task` using `repo` is still running. So when this `Task` accesses `repo` you receive your

> ObjectDisposedException

---

In the second version you use `await`. The compiler therefor translates your whole method into a *state machine*. The method returns control to its caller at the `await` statement, but *without* passing the `finally` block.
When the `Task` completes, execution of your method is continued after the `await` statement.
So `repo` is *only disposed when the `Task` has completed*. So you don't get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Answer (score 2):

Following is my understanding on initial code review:

In first one, which is not `Async` implementation but still a Task is returned from the `using block`, which would call the `repo.Dispose()` in the end, when finally `Task is executed` (assuming its done by the caller, but holds true even for the method - `GetEventParameterMRU` starting it), it's quite feasible that repo is disposed by that time, but still operation is on and thus the exception

In second one, that's not the case, even when it has freed the UI / Calling thread, until and unless following completes:

```
await repo.GetEventParameterMRU(_CurrentWorkpack, parameter, count)
```

It will not call `repo.Dispose()` and thus completely avoid the `ObjectContextDisposed` issue

Comment: Why would `repo.Dispose();` not be called in the second one? I'm pretty sure it would. No code is 'eliminated' because it is async.

Comment: @Maarten It is always called. The problem is WHEN is it called.

Comment: @Euphoric I know that, it is just that this answer suggests that the Dispose method is not called in the second example.

Comment: @Maarten I did explained, it will be called when the await is over, which saves the exception.

"until and unless following completes:
await repo.GetEventParameterMRU(_CurrentWorkpack, parameter, count)
It will not call repo.Dispose()

Answer (score 1):

Let me translate them for you:

First one:

```
Create repository
Start GetEventParameterMRU on repository as Task
Dispose repository
return Task, that is still working with repository
```

Second one:

```
Create repository
Start GetEventParameterMRU on repository as Task
Wait for Task to finish to get result
Dispose repository
return result
```

As you can see, the problem is quite clear here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the first code not capturing the current SynchronizationContext explicitly, while await DOES capture this explicitly.

Some further reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: This issue is not caused due to not capturing the Synchronization context, it is will object getting disposed while still in use